# Remove data in DW before making transaction in SSIS

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I need to remove data in table dim_customer from my database houseDW before I can make a transaction from table customer in relational database house. These data are very unique so you cannot have a dublication in the same table.

I have a sql script that remove data from the table dim_customer.

What component from the SSIS in dataflow or control flow do I need to use to execute a sql code? Maybe there are another solution in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control Flow - [Execute SQL Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx)